# How can I import this java project with no src folder into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I import the java project shown in the picture below into eclipse, since there is no `src` folder in it.

[image: Java Project Folder]

Comment: Sorry, I don't click on stray links.  No /src?  What is the project?  This is easy with IntelliJ.  Get a better IDE.

Comment: the structure of the project is :
com
javax
META-INF
org
...

Comment: Put the image in your post.  No link.  Maybe I'll look at it.  Sorry, your comment doesn't help at all.  What do you expect to get from this project after you import it?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZsC8.png

Comment: just i need to import it into eclipse

Comment: I think there's source there, it's just badly organized.  I'm guessing you'll find .java files under /com, /net, /javax, etc.  I see java_cup - is this the source for the CUP parser?  Do the import, create a /src folder, and move the packages underneath it.

Comment: Yes, you need to import.  Do it.  What's the issue?

Comment: i think it's a maven project, so i try now to import it

Comment: Excellent.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: I don't know what that looks like.  Voting to close.

Comment: it's decompiled jar

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't depend on source folders being called 'src'. You can import any directory as a "project" in eclipse and then configure the source folders from the right click -> properties -> java build path.

However, if that directory doesn't actually contain any source code, the question is if you're trying to use the classes/jars contained within. Then you need to add those classes/jars to your classpath.

Comment: i think it's a maven project, so i try now to import it